# How do you pass a function as a parameter in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

How do you specify a function as a parameter to another function in Elixir? For instance, pass foo to bar so that bar can then call foo. What is the syntax both in the calling function and the function that receives it?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Use `&Module.function/arity` to pass it, and `.(…)` to call it.

For example:

```
def my_hof(f)
    f.([1, 2, 3], &(&1 * 2))
end

my_hof(&Enum.map/2)
```

Comment: what about private functions?

Comment: Use `&function/arity` from within the same module